# Array length issue with proper use of push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm aware of the title sounds very familiar to a often asked question about associative arrays and the problem of their length. However I didn't find a solution for my problem over here on Stack Overflow yet.

The problem is, `.length` is always outputting 0 instead of the wanted amount, which in this testing case would be 12. When I output it via `console.log` I get 12 entries and I can see the length attribute with the correct value. I attached my firebug output:

```
images: Array[12] 
    0: "img1.jpg"
    1: "img2.jpg"
    2: "img3.jpg"
    3: "img4.jpg"
    4: "img5.jpg"
    5: "img6.jpg"
    6: "img7.jpg"
    7: "img8.jpg"
    8: "img9.jpg"
    9: "img10.jpg"
    10: "img11.jpg"
    11: "img12.jpg"
    length: 12
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

The following code snippet fills the array:

`this.images.push(el.toDataURL());`

when i now call `console.log(this,this.images,(this.images).length);` its always 0 instead of 12.

Any help would be appreciated.

The script on fiddle. **(output on console)**

http://jsfiddle.net/EL2xR/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle demo to show your problem?

Comment: how is `this.images` initialized?

Comment: this.images = [];

Added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say **this.img.onload** you make it asynchronous, your init is run but then immediately after the method getImages, which finds the aImages empty at that moment in time.
You should consider checking if all images are loaded before running getImages to get the correct result.

Here is a modified example that works. You can tweak it more if needed!
 http://jsfiddle.net/EL2xR/1/

```
 interval = setTimeout(function() {
                _this.getImages(from, to);
            }, 1000);
```

Check for where this.loaded appears in the code, that one flag I used to know that everything is loaded! And then with setTimeout just run the same method until loaded is true!

Comment: Omg... of course! -.- Guess you just saved me hours of searching^^ Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I solved the problem using a callback now. :) Somehow I just didn't think of the onload problem :D

Answer (score 0):

ah - i see what you mean.

So the problem is just that you are printing it to the console when it is empty, but the array contents are updated after you log it.

add this after your initial console.log to see :

```
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("Later...");
       console.log(that,that.aImages,that.aImages.length);
  });
```

Perhaps confusing you is that "this" and it's properties are live in the console, so expanding the sprite - you see that it's aImages is full, but they were empty when you first printed them.

Comment: The array is dynamically filled and I'm using images.push() to add new values to the array. As this is part of an object I have to use this.images, everything else is the same. Images array is defined via []. Still length via console.log inside the array shows 12. but direct output of this.images.length outputs 0. Also added fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/EL2xR/